# Can not grow width size in navbar with inherit class

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS3 and I practicing creating a navbar, that I want to do is to expand the width of `input text` to 50% into a navbar, I try to apply a class:

```
.main-nav__searchbar{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

But it no works

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin:0px;
}

#product-overview {
    background-color: #ff1b68;
    width: 100%;
    height: 528px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.section-title{
    color: #2ddf5c;
    }

    #product-overview h1{
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}

.main-header{
width:100%;
background: #2ddf5c;
padding:8px 16px;
}

.main-header > div{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-header__brand{
color: #0e4f1f;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
}

.main-nav__searchbar{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.main-nav{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
}

.main-nav__items{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style: none;
}
.main-nav__item{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>CSS course</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="main-header">
            <div>
                <a href="index.html" class="main-header__brand">
                    uHost
                </a></div>
                <div><input type="text" placeholder="search" class="main-nav__searchbar"></div><nav class="main-nav">
                <ul class="main-nav__items">
                    <li class="main-nav__item"> 
                        <a href="packages/index.html">Packages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="main-nav__item">
                        <a href="customers/index.html">Customers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="main-nav__item">
                        <a href="start-hosting/index.html">Start Hosting</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Why it does not work if my parent class has `display:inline-block` property as all my markups there? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `display: inline-block` tries to fit all elements in one line. For that reason, your `50%` seems very small. If you set it to `100%` of the remaining space it is much bigger.

Nevertheless, I believe it is also a good idea to become familiar with [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). You can see I used [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to re-arrange your navbar.

Now, your elements are nicely spaced between each other. Each of them takes just enough space (you can still adjust the `%`). Additionally, you achieve a decent level of responsiveness out of the box with [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin:0px;
}

#product-overview {
    background-color: #ff1b68;
    width: 100%;
    height: 528px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.section-title{
    color: #2ddf5c;
    }

    #product-overview h1{
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
}

.main-header{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-evenly;
width:100%;
background: #2ddf5c;
padding:8px 16px;
}

.main-header > div{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-header__brand{
color: #0e4f1f;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
}

.main-nav__searchbar{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.main-nav{
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
}

.main-nav__items{

display: flex;
justify-content: space-evenly;
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style: none;
}
.main-nav__item{
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>CSS course</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="main-header">
            <div>
                <a href="index.html" class="main-header__brand">
                    uHost
                </a></div>
                <div><input type="text" placeholder="search" class="main-nav__searchbar"></div><nav class="main-nav">
                <ul class="main-nav__items">
                    <li class="main-nav__item"> 
                        <a href="packages/index.html">Packages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="main-nav__item">
                        <a href="customers/index.html">Customers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="main-nav__item">
                        <a href="start-hosting/index.html">Start Hosting</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about if I want to increment more the width than 100%? if I do that it works, I.E, if I use 200%, but that is not responsive anymore, what we can do in that cases?

Comment: It all depends on how many elements you want to have in one line. It also depends on the screen size. There is no, one, clear answer that will work in all scenarios. The value of `width` for example might need to change depending on the screen size. For that, you would use media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries